# Failing to upload file in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Am having the form which I want to upload file but i got null on the fileUpload field when I submit to the controller
here is my Form

```
<form action="{{route('manager.expense.store')}}" method="POST" id="manager_add_new_expense" enctype="multipart/form-data">
enter code here
<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="example-input-palaceholder">Add Supporting Document</label><small class="ml-auto align-self-end"><b>
  <a href="#" class="font-weight-light">Doc Such as: Receipt, Mpawe, Orders, Etc ...</a></b></small>
  <input type="file" class="form-control @error('Uploadfile') is-invalid @enderror" id="Uploadfile" name="Uploadfile" value="">
```

Also my controller content bellow

```
//
    $user = User::findOrFail(Auth::id());

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
      'Uploadfile' => 'required|mimes:doc,docx,pdf,txt,png,jpg|max:500000'
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()){
      // return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        return response()->json(["error"=>true, "message"=>$validator->errors()->first()]);
    }
    $filename = $request->file('Uploadfile');
    $filen = date('YmdHis')."-".$filename->getClientOriginalName();
    $request->file('Uploadfile')->move(storage_path('expensefile'), $filen);
```

I don't know why I am getting the Null value, only Am failing on the the validation like I have no file found.

Comment: Where do you get null?

Comment: on input type='file'; I choose the file as well but when i try this $request->file('Uploadfile'); it is having no file

Comment: I can not see `@csrf` btw, is it missing?

Comment: Are you getting the execption or it is returning null? If that is an exception can you paste the exception stack trace? Also please add the controller method body with signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the Error was i was submitting the form using AJAX yet there was no code to enable the upload

Just I added this and it works

```
  data: new FormData(this),
  contentType: false,
  cache: false,
  processData:false,
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding @csrf and make sure your route is a post route